# How to group data into varables based on column values in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have data of the form:

```
p   q   r   y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_5 y_6 y_7
2   8   14  0748    0748    0748    0790    0804    0818    0832
2   9   22  1262    1262    1262    1328    1350    1372    1394
1   5   19  0512    0512    0512    0569    0588    0607    0626
2   7   19  0748    0748    0748    0805    0824    0843    0862
3   11  13  1608    1608    1608    1647    1660    1673    1686
2   7   20  0788    0788    0788    0848    0868    0888    0908
1   4   15  0310    0310    0310    0355    0370    0385    0400
3   12  17  2130    2130    2130    2181    2198    2215    2232
1   4   14  0280    0280    0280    0322    0336    0350    0364
1   5   20  0552    0552    0552    0612    0632    0652    0672
2   7   17  0674    0674    0674    0725    0742    0759    0776
3   10  13  1276    1276    1276    1315    1328    1341    1354
3   11  20  1846    1846    1846    1906    1926    1946    1966
3   11  14  1636    1636    1636    1678    1692    1706    1720
1   6   18  0566    0566    0566    0620    0638    0656    0674
3   12  16  2096    2096    2096    2144    2160    2176    2192
2   9   21  1218    1218    1218    1281    1302    1323    1344
3   10  19  1474    1474    1474    1531    1550    1569    1588
2   8   13  0720    0720    0720    0759    0772    0785    0798
1   6   22  0730    0730    0730    0796    0818    0840    0862
1   4   13  0252    0252    0252    0291    0304    0317    0330
2   8   15  0778    0778    0778    0823    0838    0853    0868
3   12  15  2064    2064    2064    2109    2124    2139    2154
3   10  16  1366    1366    1366    1414    1430    1446    1462
2   9   16  1028    1028    1028    1076    1092    1108    1124
1   5   16  0404    0404    0404    0452    0468    0484    0500
1   6   21  0686    0686    0686    0749    0770    0791    0812
```

I would like to sort these arrays with NumPy and group the data into variables based on same values of q as shown below:

```
    1   4   13  0252    0252    0252    0291    0304    0317    0330
q_a 1   4   14  0280    0280    0280    0322    0336    0350    0364
    1   4   15  0310    0310    0310    0355    0370    0385    0400
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   5   16  0404    0404    0404    0452    0468    0484    0500
q_b 1   5   19  0512    0512    0512    0569    0588    0607    0626
    1   5   20  0552    0552    0552    0612    0632    0652    0672
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   6   18  0566    0566    0566    0620    0638    0656    0674
q_c 1   6   21  0686    0686    0686    0749    0770    0791    0812
    1   6   22  0730    0730    0730    0796    0818    0840    0862
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    2   7   17  0674    0674    0674    0725    0742    0759    0776
q_d 2   7   19  0748    0748    0748    0805    0824    0843    0862
    2   7   20  0788    0788    0788    0848    0868    0888    0908
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    2   8   13  0720    0720    0720    0759    0772    0785    0798
q_e 2   8   14  0748    0748    0748    0790    0804    0818    0832
    2   8   15  0778    0778    0778    0823    0838    0853    0868
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    2   9   16  1028    1028    1028    1076    1092    1108    1124
q_f 2   9   21  1218    1218    1218    1281    1302    1323    1344
    2   9   22  1262    1262    1262    1328    1350    1372    1394
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    3   10  13  1276    1276    1276    1315    1328    1341    1354
q_g 3   10  16  1366    1366    1366    1414    1430    1446    1462
    3   10  19  1474    1474    1474    1531    1550    1569    1588
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    3   11  13  1608    1608    1608    1647    1660    1673    1686
q_h 3   11  14  1636    1636    1636    1678    1692    1706    1720
    3   11  20  1846    1846    1846    1906    1926    1946    1966
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    3   12  15  2064    2064    2064    2109    2124    2139    2154
q_i 3   12  16  2096    2096    2096    2144    2160    2176    2192
    3   12  17  2130    2130    2130    2181    2198    2215    2232
```

I am still struggling to group the data based on the values of q. My effort so far was able to sort out the data only:

```
import numpy as np

data = open('data.dat', "r")
line = data.readline()
while line.startswith('#'):
    line = data.readline()
data_header = line.split("\t")
data_header[-1] = data_header[-1].strip()

_data_ = np.genfromtxt(data, comments='#', delimiter='\t', names = data_header, dtype = None, unpack = True).transpose()
sorted_index =  np.lexsort((_data_['r'], _data_['q'], _data_['p']))
_data_ =  _data_[sorted_index]

p_ind = np.nonzero(np.diff(_data_['p']))[0]
q_ind = np.nonzero(np.diff(_data_['q']))[0]
r_ind = np.nonzero(np.diff(_data_['r']))[0]

n_p =  len(np.nonzero(np.diff(_data_['p']))[0]) + 1
n_q =  len(np.nonzero(np.diff(_data_['q']))[0]) + 1
n_r =  len(np.nonzero(np.diff(_data_['r']))[0]) + 1
```

Are there any functions in NumPy/SciPy that can group data based on values?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is what you are looking for but it may be helpful.

Use pandas.DataFrame to store your data and then the option groupby

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                    'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                       'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                'C' : np.random.choice(8), 'D' : np.random.choice(8)})

list(df.groupby(['A', 'B'])
```